# inject() must be called from an injection context Angular Microapp module federation

Tags: angular, angular-material, webpack-module-federation, angular-module-federation

I have an Angular app with some microapps in it using module federation. When I Log-In to it and try to access those microapps "SOMETIMES RANDOMLY" I get the inject() must be called from an injection context error and that route is not opened, I have not been able to find the root cause since it happens sometimes.

I have 2 libraries created for the project, so 2 extra package.json all the 3 angular/core versions are same ie 12.2.0.

Have tried multiple solutions on stackoverflow with heading inject() must be called from an injection context, such as adding preservesymlink true, adding "@angular/*": [ "./node_modules/@angular/*" ], this in tsconfig.json,

Tried making singlton to false, giving requiredVersion as 12.2.0 instead of auto

Also tried adding this in index.html

`<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" /> <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" /> <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" /> <meta name="cache-control" content="no-cache" />`

stack trace of the error

[image]

the app-routing

[image]

Here are some of the settings of my app.

[image]

Comment: Why do you have `@angular/*` packages as `singletone: false`? You're loading angular modules more than once (and potentially with slightly different versions) and this is, most likely, the root cause.

Comment: It was actually singleton: true and requiredVersion: auto but changed to the current to try one of the possible solutions mentioned on the web, changing it to true also doesnt work

Comment: Ok, could you share the initial setup (as text, not as picture), details of what you've tried so far, and the stack trace of the error (or just info regarding what exactly it tries to inject when fails)?

Comment: just updated the question kindly check @Shlang

Comment: Check if `npm ls @angular/router` shows the same version for every involved project.

Comment: When I run this at root project it just shows one @angular/router@12.2.0

Comment: And what about the app you load lazily - this `remoteEntry.js` are you sure it does not have ` @angular/router` built-in?

Comment: I have 5 micro apps and 2 libraries inside the main project, none of that is named remoteEntry.js and yes the 5 micro apps and one main app have same @angular/router@12.2.0 and the 2 libraries don't have router the cmd returns empty